# Нужна ли запятая после слова "днём"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

**Жарким августовским днём мы с сыном, спустившись в кафе "Паркинг", встретили веселого и необычного человека.**

Answer (score 2):

Встретили (когда?) *жарким августовским днем* — это обстоятельство времени, которое не нуждается в выделении запятыми.

Обособление обстоятельства необходимо в следующих случаях:
если они выражены деепричастным оборотом (в вашем предложении это *спустившись в кафе "Паркинг"*);
если они представляют собой сравнительный оборот;
если они начинаются с предлога НЕСМОТРЯ НА.
[Обособление обстоятельств](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_177)

*Однажды **жарким летним днем** мы возвращались с дедом домой, ели лимонный лед, как вдруг ему позвонили* (В. Шваб).
*И вот **жарким августовским днём** Мара провожала его туда на перроне Казанского вокзала столицы* (Б. Сударов).
*Четверть века назад **жарким июльским днем** мы подъезжали к белым саманным домикам станицы Змейской, спрятавшимся в тени абрикосовых и грушевых деревьев* (В. Ковалевская).

Answer (score 1):

**Жарким августовским днём** //мы с сыном, спустившись в кафе "Паркинг", встретили веселого и необычного человека.

***Жарким августовским днём***  — обстоятельственный оборот со значением **времени,** выраженный падежной формой.

В начале предложения  такая конструкция **обычно** не обособляется, так как входит в основное сообщение.

Детерминант отделяется от предложения небольшой произносительной **паузой**, но эта пауза не обозначается запятой.

**Примечание**

**Может ли обстоятельственный оборот со значением времени обособляться?** Это зависит от позиции оборота, его распространенности, а также от структуры предложения. (**Здесь нет абсолютно однозначного решения:** если это обстоятельство времени, то оно никогда не обособляется).

Примеры с обособлением:

Этим я занимался около трех лет, **в вечернее время**, дома и в Ленинской библиотеке. [С. П. Капица. Мои воспоминания (2008)] (Оборот со значением уточнения в середине предложения).

**Только с наступлением по-настоящему теплых и солнечных дней**, наконец-то мы решились отправиться на нашу первую велосипедную прогулку.  (Структура предложения влияет на его обособление).

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна: сочетание "жарким августовским днем" - такое же обстоятельство времени, как и "вчера". Наличие паузы (для переведения дыхания) после этого слова само по себе не является основанием для запятой - русская пунктуация больше подчинена расчленению на грамматические конструкции, чем интонации.

Comment: Alex_ander, можно Вам задать "тестовые" вопросы (нужно выбрать правильные ответы): 1) обстоятельство времени никогда не обособляется; 2) обстоятельство времени никогда не обособляется в начале предложения; 3) в начале предложения возможно обособление обстоятельства времени в некоторых случаях (например, при распространенности оборота, когда он близок по значению к придаточному времени).

Comment: Нельзя, я скептически отношусь к любым обобщениям и сам ими не пользуюсь :) .

Comment: Извините, я не ожидала такой реакции.  "Тесты" хотя и выглядят обобщенно, но они непосредственно относятся к теме заданного вопроса. Фактически я спрашивала о том, почему обстоятельство времени "не нуждается в выделении запятыми, " как это очень категорично прозвучало в одном из ответов.

Comment: Вопрос был о конкретном предложении и не содержал пожеланий подвести решение под правило. Я просто свёл менее очевидный случай к более очевидному: "вчера" и "в тот (или иной) прекрасный день" в равной мере относятся к необособляемым "дням". Это позволяет сомневающемуся без необходимости не обращаться к книгам.

Comment: Да, спасибо,  на самом деле у меня не было вопросов и замечаний по   Вашему ответу, просто было интересно  узнать именно Ваше мнение. Еще раз извините.